# How to access Twitter in Xcode 9 Simulator when Apple remove it from Settings?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitter, xcode9-beta

I'm trying to learn Swift on iOS 10 + Swift 3 Course of Stanford. But I'm coding with Xcode 9 - iOS 11 - Swift 4. When I want to access Twitter to fetch the data from the Twitter framework, there is an error:

> "TwitterRequest: Access to Twitter was not granted."

We can fix this bug, by the way, is going to Settings and Sign in Twitter but in iOS 11, Apple has removed it from Settings
I do not how to access Twitter, please help me. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Huu Phong Nguyen, how did you solve this problem? The same issue also exists with the Facebook app in the same course. IMO, this is unnacceptable as I am paying for a Coursera Specialization.

Comment: @Avrdan Maybe Facebook no longer supports by iOS 12 now. Let's try Facebook API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 11 no longer supports using Twitter through the built-in social framework. Instead, you can use Twitter Kit 3 to Tweet, log in users, and use the Twitter API.

Take a look at [this guide](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/migrate-social-framework). But overall it got more complicated to accomplish Twitter login and if you are just getting started with iOS development I'd recommend skipping this step if possible.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it. It's really more complicated.